# dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier crash 'could not dequeue a view of kind" UICollectionElementKindCell' on rotation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionviewcell

I'm using prototype cell. But I'm getting the following error only on rotation. Please help me to fix this issue

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: `'could not dequeue a view of kind: UICollectionElementKindCell with identifier Cell` - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'

I’m using Prototype cells and cell identifier is correct. I’m getting the crash only on rotation

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                          cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  if (_currentSelectedIndex == kFPSearchSegmentTypeOthers) {
    if ((self.searchProductRecipesOrOthersArray &&
      indexPath.item < self.searchProductRecipesOrOthersArray.count)) {
       FPSearchRecipesOthersCollectionViewCell *cell =
         [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:
         kFPSearchRecipesOther‌​sCollectionViewCellI‌​dentifier
         forIndexPath:indexPath];
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: is it working fine when you scroll the tableView in portrait mode ?

Comment: Yes. I Couldn't find any issues. I'm getting this crash only on rotation

Comment: If you are using auto layouts then check the constraints properly .

Comment: This is my code FPProductCollectionViewCell *cell = (FPProductCollectionViewCell*)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:kFPFPProductCollectionViewCell forIndexPath:indexPath];

Comment: Problem is not with storyboard. If the array contains less items, it is working fine

Comment: can you post some relevant code for your question and at which point your app is crashing ?

Comment: where are you using the above code?

Comment: You should post your code in context with the `cellForItemAtIndexPath` method (in your original question, not as a comment). Where do you register your cells? In code (please share!) or in Interface Builder?

Comment: I’m using Prototype cells and cell identifier is correct. I’m getting the crash only on rotation

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

if (_currentSelectedIndex == kFPSearchSegmentTypeOthers){

        if ((self.searchProductRecipesOrOthersArray && indexPath.item < self.searchProductRecipesOrOthersArray.count)){
            FPSearchRecipesOthersCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:kFPSearchRecipesOthersCollectionViewCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];}}}